# Is there an equivalent function in kotlin for numpy polyfit?

Tags: java, numpy, kotlin, scipy, linear-regression

I'm new to kotlin and I have to perform a linear fitting on a binary mask. Applying threshold I get a set of points, and from these points I have to extract the slope and origin of the line.

I'm used to do it on Python with numpy polyfit, is there an equivalent function in kotlin for this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: While I don't have the answer to this, here's a link to quite a few libraries that you can explore to find if they have something similar. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-science-overview.html#kotlin-libraries

Comment: May be worth stressing that if you're using Kotlin/JVM, then you can use _any_ Java libraries (whether they were written in Java or Kotlin or any other JVM language). Kotlin's standard library doesn't contain much numerical/scientific stuff — but it doesn't need to, because there are so many third-party libraries out there. (Just as NumPy is apparently a third-party Python library.)